# Reinforcement Learning cartpole

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

i'm trying to get my feet wet in reinforced learning and come across this cartpole problem,
i already trained the model and got a score of 500 (which is way above the passing 200?). I also saved the training file and the model file, but when i test the model and try to predict the action using model.predict it comes with an error.

Code snippet:

```
environment_name = "CartPole-v1"
env = gym.make(environment_name, render_mode='human')

episodes = 5
for episodes in range(1, episodes + 1):
    obs = env.reset()
    done = False
    score = 0

    while not done:
        env.render()

        # this is the key change
        action, _ = model.predict(obs)  # we're now using our model here!
        obs, reward, done, info = env.step(action)

        score += reward
    print("Episode: {} Score: {}".format(episodes, score))
env.close()
```

Error in the code:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
    Input In [14], in <cell line: 2>()
          8 env.render()
         10 # this is the key change
    ---> 11 action, _= model.predict(obs) # we're now using our model here!
         12 obs, reward, done,
    
    ValueError: Error: Unexpected observation shape (2,) for Box environment, please use (4,) or (n_env, 4) for the observation shape.
```

i am expecting an output where the cartpole is balance since im getting a high training score.

i try to look at the obs:

```
env = gym.make('CartPole-v1')
obs = env.reset()
len(obs)
```

---

2

why the obs tuple is only 2 shouldn't it be 4? because the model.predict expected an input of (4,)?

Answer (score 1):

.reset() **does not** return observation. [It returns a **tuple** (observation, info)](https://www.gymlibrary.dev/api/core/#gym.Env.reset).

Change your code to

```
obs, info = env.reset()
```

Comment: The problem is that whenever i check env.reset() the result is like this:

    (array([-0.03750503, -0.02625694, -0.00306027,  0.03739002], dtype=float32),
     {})

which makes it a tupple of size 2, instead of the expected result:

    array([-0.03750503, -0.02625694, -0.00306027,  0.03739002], dtype=float32)

Comment: which is exactly what I wrote in the answer. Second element is the "info" dictionary, just discard it